# Proving an integer is non-negative by showing there is a vector space with it as its dimension.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, vector-spaces

The other day I attended a lecture on methods to show whether or not a number is an integer. We were given examples of showing it is the number of ways to count something, and to show there exist groups and subgroups and then apply Lagrange's theorem. But it was stated that from time to time it crops up where in order to prove that an integer is non-negative, one must show there exists a vector space with it as the dimension, hence proving it can't be negative. I really like the sound of this, but no example was given.

Could someone give a problem and solution demonstrating this method of proof?

Or at least allude to one.

Comment: Well, $1$ is a non-negative integer. Reason: the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R$ has dimension $1$. Now seriously, to show that a certain number is a non-negative integer by your method is a *decidedly* complicated way to proceed, because when you describe at first your candidate-to-non-negative-integer, probably you are already giving a lot of information about it.

Comment: This is a very weird question: first, I've never heard of such a thing (but this could probably only serve to show my ignorance), but that "one *must* show that there's a vector space of dimension a number to prove that number is positive" seems to be pretty ridiculous: first, who says dimension can't be fractional or negative or evne irrational? And if we already know that dimension **has** to be positive and integer, then how this serves the purpose we wanted to begin with!? Weird...

Comment: I don't understand the two critical comments. The idea isn't to show that a certain number like $1$ is non-negative, but that a number given in some more indirect way, e.g. as the difference of two unknown counts, is non-negative. And @Don: I'm not sure what the point of your comment is. The question assumes that we already know that the dimension of a vector space is a non-negative integer. I don't understand why you say that in this case the proof doesn't serve the purpose. The purpose is to prove that the number is non-negative, and that purpose is served if it's identified as a dimension.

Comment: As I wrote, @Joriki: I can't see the point of such an exercise and, apparently, not many have met this thing of "must show..." as I can't see any answers so far. My point is, I think, clear: assuming dimensions to be positive integers, to show say $\,4\,$ is positive (and integer) I can say that $\,\dim_{\Bbb R}C^2=4\,$ and that's all...and how did you get that number? By first counting elements in a base of whatever, which assumes you *already know* you're dealing with positive integers to begin with...as if all the info about possible dimensions is already known. For me this is weird.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I do believe there might be a natural situation when the argument in question is useful. In analogy to the idea of using groups/subgroups/Lagrange, one could encounter a situation where the easiest way to show that $a$ is a positive integer is to construct a vector space $V$ with dimension $\operatorname{dim} V = a + n$ and a subspace $W$ with dimension $\operatorname{dim} W = n$. Now, $a = \operatorname{dim} V/W$ is the dimension of the quotient space, hence non-negative.

Comment: This situation sometimes arises in representation theory.  For example, the fact that a plethysm of Schur functions has positive coefficients in the Schur basis relies on the interpretation of the coefficients as dimensions of irreducible representations.  See Richard Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 2, Theorem A2.7 (and the comment following it.)

Comment: I think that Hausdorf might take umbrage with this.

Comment: Positivity of coefficients of Kazhdan-Lustig polynomials is another example coming from representation theory. This positivity is best seen from cohomological interpretation of the coefficients.

Answer (score 11):

Here are two examples; I am afraid that complexity-wise they are a bit high for this site, but here it goes. Both examples share the property that certain numbers defined *originally* in combinatorial terms, are proven to be nonegative integers via their cohomological interpretation. (One can manufacture artificial examples of the same phenomenon by starting with some combinatorial quantities, like dimensions of some representations, which are manifestly nonnegative and then use alternative combinatorial descriptions of these quantities, where positivity is obscured. However, this is cheating, since such quantities are typically *originally defined* so that their nonegativity is clear.)

(1). **McMullen's conjecture (Stanley theorem).** Given a (rational) convex polytope $P\subset {\mathbb R}^d$, one defines a combinatorial quantity which captures numbers of faces of various dimensions, called [$H$-vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-vector): $(h_0,...,h_d)$. Even though it is more obscure (at the first glance) than the *$F$-vector* (the vector $F=(f_0,...f_d)$ simply records numbers of faces of $P$ of dimensions $0$ through $d$), it contains the same information and has better structural properties:
$$
h_k= \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} {d-i\choose k-i} f_{i-1}. 
$$

Peter McMullen conjectured that 
$$
1=h_0\le h_1\le h_2\le ...\le h_m, \quad m=[d/2]. 
$$ 
One can think of this conjecture as positivity of the differences $\delta_i=h_i-h_{i-1}$. Note that even positivity of the given $h_i$ (for $i$ large) is not immediate since its definition involves an alternating sum. Richard Stanley proved (see Corollary 3.2 [here](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/69.pdf)) McMullen's conjecture by reinterpreting the problem in algebro-geometric fashion, where the numbers $h_i$ are dimensions of *intersection cohomology groups* $IH^{2i}(X)$ for a toric variety $X$ associated with $P$. Then the numbers $\delta_i$ appear as coranks of the maps (cup products with the Kahler class of $X$) 
$$
IH^{2i-2}(X)\to IH^{2i}(X)
$$ 
coming from the hard Lefschetz theorem.

(2). **Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomials**. There are important polynomials, called *Kazhdan–Lusztig* polynomials (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan-Lusztig_polynomial)) $P_{y,w}$ associated with Coxeter groups $W$ ($y$ and $w$ are elements of $W$ satisfying the inequality $y\le w$ in the Bruhat order on $W$). These polynomials appear  as matrix coefficients in transition matrices from one basis to another in representations of Hecke algebras. The fact that coefficients of these polynomials are nonegative integers is not obvious at all. For finite Weyl groups (of crystallographic type) positivity and integrality of these coefficients again follows from their interpretation as dimensions of certain intersection cohomology groups. For general Coxeter groups positivity and integrality again follows from a cohomological interpretation of these coefficients (they again appear as dimensions of certain vector spaces). See the same wikipedia article above for details and references.

Answer (score 5):

I like the question, and add another example:

Let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix, and let $k$ be the rank of $M$. 
How do you show that $n-k$ is a non-negative integer?

You prove that $n-k$ is the dimension of the space of solutions of the system $MX=0$.

Answer (score 3):

I propose the [Riemann Roch formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Roch_theorem).

It is a very powerful tool in algebraic geometry. This formula relates four quantities which are integers. The proof, which is a wonderful but not simple piece of mathematics, proceeds exactly by showing that one of the quantities in play is the dimension of a certain vector space.

Comment: The question is about 'Proving an integer is non-negative by showing there is a vector space with it as its dimension'. All quantities in RR are manifestly non-negative integers, aren't they?..

Comment: Yes you are right, the quantities in the formula are non-negative integers. But in the proof you kind of prove that. I mean, once you show that an integer is the dimension of a vector space, than it is manifestly non-negative. But before you show that, how can you tell is positive?

Answer (score 1):

There is something half-way between the two techniques you propose: namely, proving that an integer is non-negative by showing that it counts *something*. Counting bases of vector spaces is just one particular instance of that, and one can always reduce to that case because any set can be made into a free vector space with dimension equal to the cardinality of the original set.

A fun example combining both situations is the *necklace-counting problem*. Let $M(k, n)$ be the number of necklaces on $n$ beads of $k$ colors. Then

$$M(k,n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(n/d) k^d$$

where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. It is neither immediately obvious that $M(k, n)>0$ or that $M(k,n)$ is an integer. (In fact, it's not very hard to see directly that $M(k,n)>0$ because the term $k^n$ dominates the rest of the sum, but it's still nice to have it for free. Proving that $M(k,n)$ is an integer without relying on this combinatorial interpretation is trickier.)